# openldap : 'Can't contact LDAP server' error for the same connection handle that worked fine till then

Tags: ibm-mq, openldap

I'm building an openldap user authentication module, in C, that we want to use with MQ Authentication. We are currently initializing the ldap structure ( ie. calling ldap_init() ) at the time of the program startup and then using that same Ldap handle when ever we get an authentication request ( using ldap_simple_bind_s( ld, BASEDN, pass ) ).

The problem now we are having is that, to certain amount of time ( probably about 2 hours, but could be environment dependent ) ldap_simple_bind_s() is returning LDAP_SUCCESS, but the same ldap handle which is been successful later fails with an error 
( -1) - Can't contact LDAP server .

To be sure that the hostname is not changed, I did try to get the LDAP hostname when the issue starts happening, using :
ldap_get_option (ld, LDAP_OPT_HOST_NAME, &hostname);
and that's been exactly the same.

Of course if I use the ldap_init() once again I will get a new handle which works fine, but we are not able to do that within MQ as it create some memory access issue ( addressed not mapped ). So I would like to ideally re-instantiate the same handle, which was working till then.

Do you think is there any ways to do that.?
I'm using openldap 2.3.43 library, and the application is running on Linux.

Do you think the new TCP KEEPALIVE options that is been introduced on 2.4 openldap will help here?

Also I can see an option LDAP_OPT_RESTART, can it be used in this context?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is EXTREMELY tricky to get LDAP code to work correctly inside an MQ exit. I know, I have spent years perfecting MQAUSX to work correctly across 10 distributed platforms. Each platform has its own weird and goofy issues when compiling and linking LDAP and a MQ security exit.

OpenLDAP v2.3.* is old and different iterations have different/weird bugs.  I just spent months (in 2013) working with the customer and Novell to fix some LDAP issues in SLES 11 SP2 on x86 64-bit.

Finally, you appear not to understand parallel processing of channels in MQ.  Channels can be invoked on different threads and also in different processes depending on the setting of your channels.

Just out of curiosity, how many days have you spent working on this issue and how many days, in total, have you spent creating an MQ security exit?  By your other posts, it appears you are approaching a month - is that correct?